# Why does this moving circle vibrate during drag?

Tags: android, event-handling, drawing

I wrote my own `extends View`, but it works bad. It's purpose is to allow drag the red circle. Unfortunately, circle vibrates during drag, i.e. not moving smoothly:

```
public class FieldView extends View {

private int cellWidth;
private int cellHeight;
private float startleft, starttop;
private float startx, starty;

private Paint paint;

public FieldView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(
            getTranslationX()-(float)cellWidth/2f, 
            getTranslationY() - (float)cellHeight/2f, 
            getTranslationX() + (float)cellWidth/2f, 
            getTranslationY() + (float)cellHeight/2f), paint);

}

public void setCellWidth(int value) {
    this.cellWidth = value;
}

public void setCellHeight(int value) {
    this.cellHeight = value;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if( event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
        startx = event.getX();
        starty = event.getY();
        startleft = getTranslationX();
        starttop = getTranslationY();
        return true;
    }

    else if( event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {

        setTranslationX( startleft + (event.getX() - startx) );
        setTranslationY( starttop + (event.getY() - starty) );

        invalidate();

        startx = starty = 0;
        return true;
    }

    else if( event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE ) {
        setTranslationX( startleft + (event.getX() - startx) );
        setTranslationY( starttop + (event.getY() - starty) );

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}

 }
```

Runner:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    FieldView fieldView = new FieldView(this);

    fieldView.setCellHeight(100);
    fieldView.setCellWidth(100);

    setContentView(fieldView);


}
```

THe question is: WHY??

**EDIT 1**

I don't think this is a noise, since jumping occurs with relatively big amplitude.

**FIXED**

It was a bug. My usage of get/setTranslationX/Y() was interfering with touch event coordinates. Obviously, event takes translation into account. When I changed to my own translation fields, vibration disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

A touchscreeen is not a perfect device, there will be some noise in the coordinates.  Updating too frequently, especially without any smoothing, will cause the circle to jump around due to the noise in the reported coordinates.

Probably you want to do one or both of:

- Update less frequently, or especially only update if the coordinates have changed by at least a minimum amount
- Implement a smoothing filter, for example a running average, or fancier algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I've only worked briefly with touch interfaces, but i would imagine if your fingers are like most others, they touch many places on the screen at once.

The feed back you get may be more in line with the average of the point that is the greatest on the screen during touch.

Try averaging out the number of onTouchEvent's you'll handle.  Put it at a set fps, so that some calls are ignored, but still a high enough FPS to create a nice smooth drag.

You may also want to do some kind of input filtering / averaging as well, so that a point received can never be greater than the average of the previous X amount of inputs received.  So in the event your fingers (like mine) are a bit pudgy, it evens itself out.